# jwt cookie is not in request header after logging in until i refresh the page

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, jwt

on `/login` the cookie is set and redirects to the dashboard **(pic 1)**. the `/survey_count` call returns 401 from jwt authentication (**pic 2**) but then on refresh it is 200 **(pic 3)** and every other call that has the jwt authentication middleware works and returns 200. need the `/survey_count` call to return 200 and have the `blossom_token` in the Cookie request header. not sure what the issue is

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
// axios call on the frontend 
 const login = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post(
        `${endpoint}/login`,
        {
          email: loginData.email,
          password: loginData.password,
        },
        {withCredentials: true}
      );
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    }
  };
```

```
// express setup

const express = require("express");
const config = require("./config");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2022-08-01",
});
const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
  methods: "POST, PUT, GET ,OPTIONS, DELETE",
};


app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  next();
});
```

```
// authentication middleware
const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.blossom_token;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized"});
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).json({message: "Forbidden"});
    }
    req.user_id = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};
```

```
// login function 
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    const response = await pool.query(
      "SELECT id, (password = crypt($1, password)) AS verified FROM users WHERE email = $2",
      [password, email]
    );
    if (response.error) {
      console.log(response.error);
    }

    let {verified, id} = response.rows[0];
    if (verified) {
      const token = jwt.sign({id}, process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN); //TODO: expire with refresh token
      res.cookie("blossom_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        path: "/",
      });
      // Set Cache-Control header to no-cache
      res.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

      res.json({token: token});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({message: "Invalid credentials"});
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

```
// survey_count using the authenticate middleware
app.get("/survey_count", authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user_id = req.user_id;
    const count = await pool.query(
      "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM survey WHERE user_id = $1",
      [user_id]
    );

    res.json(count.rows[0].count);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```